# Input() function works only in specific cases

Tags: python, random, input, while-loop, translation

I created this code in order to study english by translating the words which are inside a txt file. The problem I have is that the program works only when I translate the word "lampada" into "lamp", and not with the others.
Code:

```
import random

a = 1
while a > 0:
    k = open('Informazioni.txt', 'r+')
    read = k.readlines()
    while True:
        domanda = random.randint(0, len(read) - 1)
        if domanda % 2 == 0:
            risposta = domanda + 1
            break
    question = read[domanda]
    solution = read[risposta]
    print(question)
    c = 2
    while c != 3:
        response = input()
        if response == solution:
            c = 3
```

the txt content is:

auto
car
regalo
gift
lampada
lamp

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that each line in the Informazioni.txt file also contains the ‘\n’ character to go to the end. Only the last line doesn't have it and so the code works.
Try this code:

```
 if risposta != len(read)-1:
    solution = read[risposta][:-1]
 else:
    solution = read[risposta]
```

Instead:

```
solution = read[risposta]
```

It works.